# How to subtract a constant value from all elements of an array?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an array and for example I want to subtract  like 7 from all elements of the array. How can I do that except the below logic.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i]-=7;
}
```

Anything related streams will be helpful.

Edit- It should not necessary be an array. It can be an ArrayList also.

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Looks like straightforward 'map()'.

Comment: `Arrays.setAll(array, ix -> array[ix]-7)` or `parallelSetAll(array, ix -> array[ix]-7)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With streams you can use `map` like this :

```
int[] array = {-1, 8, 9};
array = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(i -> i - 7)
        .toArray();
```

or if you are using List you can use :

```
List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-1, 8, 9));
array = array.stream()
        .map(i -> i - 7)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same as modifying the existing array: you're creating a new array.

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel I read the question again I don't read that the OP mention to not create a new array!

Comment: But it can be an important distinction if you expect an in-situ change of the existing array. And personally, I read _"I have an array and [..] I want to subtract like 7 from all elements of the array."_ as a request to update the existing array.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I can't arrive to a solution using stream without except this way, do you have any idea?

Comment: Consider looking at `Arrays.setAll` as suggested by Holger in the comments (or including that in your answer). The javadoc of those methods also suggest a stream like solution (where you stream the indexes, not the contents of the array), which is used in the implementation of `setAll`.

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel Already [@Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51698428/5558072) mention that in his answer

Answer (score 3):

while stream may seem "new and cool", you should keep in mind what is actually happening.

the code:

```
array = Arrays.stream(array)
             .map(i -> i - 7)
             .toArray();
```

actually runs something like this (but worse...):

```
int[] newArray = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     newArray[i] = array[i]-7;
}
array = newArray;
```

so you can easily see how less efficient it is compared to your own code.

not to say it doesn't work, but DO keep in mind.

- if it's an arraylist you can use lst.set(i, lst.get(i) - 7), by the way...

Answer (score 3):

Streams are supposed to be side-effect free, so a stream is not a good choice for modifying the contents of an array or list. Something similar is possible, though.

The **`ArrayList`** first. I consider this a nice way (then again the `for` loop is nice too):

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(11,  14, 9, 13));
    list.replaceAll(e -> e - 7);
    System.out.println(list);
```

> [4, 7, 2, 6]

The `replaceAll` method was introduced in Java 8.

I don’t think a nice solution for **the `int` array** exists. You *might* do:

```
    int[] array = { 11,  14, 9, 13 };
    Arrays.setAll(array, ix -> array[ix] - 7);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

> [4, 7, 2, 6]

I don’t find it natural nor easy to read and would prefer the `for` loop.

If you happened to have an array of non-null `Integer`, the first approach above could be used through `Arrays.asList`:

```
    Integer[] array = { 11,  14, 9, 13 };
    Arrays.asList(array).replaceAll(e -> e - 7);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

> [4, 7, 2, 6]